# How to describe the set of real numbers x satisfying inequalities like this

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

I am a little bit confused how to approach tasks like this:

$$ \frac{5x}{4}\le \left | \sqrt{1+x} - \sqrt{1-x} \right |\leq \sqrt{2} $$

Comment: Please, if you are ok, you can accept the answer and set it as solved. Thanks!

Comment: I don't think I consider this as 'solved', to be honest.

Comment: do you need more details?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Domain: $-1 \le x \le 1$. If $-1 \le x\le 0$, the left inequality is already true, so you only need to solve the right one. Square both sides of it:

$2 - 2\sqrt{1-x^2}\le 2$, which is true also. Thus $-1 \le x \le 0$ is one solution set. If $0 \le x \le 1$, then: $\dfrac{25x^2}{4}\le 2-2\sqrt{1-x^2}\le 2$ . Observe the right inequality is true and take care of the the left: $2\sqrt{1-x^2}\le2-\dfrac{5x^2}{4}$ . This requires: $\dfrac{5x^2}{4}\le 2\implies x^2\le \dfrac{8}{5}$, and since $x^2 \le 1$, this condition is satisfied, and both sides are non negative. Square both sides: $4(1-x^2) \le 4- 5x^2+\dfrac{25x^4}{16}\implies 16x^2-25x^4 \le 0 \implies x^2(16-25x^2) \le 0\implies 25x^2 \ge 16\implies x \le -4/5$ or $x \ge 4/5$ . Thus: $-1 \le x \le -4/5$  or $4/5 \le x \le 1$. Since $0 \le x \le 1$, you have another solution set $4/5 \le x \le 1$ . Combining the two cases, the final solution set for this question is: $[-1,0] \cup [\frac{4}{5}, 1]$ .

Comment: Thank you very much! But I have few questions: I don't understand where was $\frac{25x^{2}}{4}$ derived. If we square $\frac{5x}{4}$ don't we get $\frac{25x^{2}}{16}$?

Comment: Originally its $\dfrac{5x}{2}$.

Comment: But where did you get $ \frac{5x}{2} $?

Answer (score 1):

It's not a simply inequality. You have to handle it with care. If you don't want to take any risk you have to proceed in the following way.

Firstly observe that for existence of the square root you have to check that

$1+x \geq 0$ and $1-x \geq 0$

that is

$x \geq -1$ and $x \leq 1 $

thus $$-1 \leq x \leq 1 $$

Now to solve you need to consider separately 2 cases:

1. $\sqrt{1+x} - \sqrt{1-x} \ge 0 $ that is $0\leq x \leq 1$
2. $\sqrt{1+x} - \sqrt{1-x} < 0$ that is $-1 \leq x <0 $

**in the case 1** as $0\leq x \leq 1$ the inequality becomes

$\frac{5x}{4}\le \sqrt{1+x} - \sqrt{1-x} \leq \sqrt{2}$

**in the case 2** as $-1 \leq x <0 $ the inequality becomes

$\frac{5x}{4}\le \sqrt{1-x} - \sqrt{1+x} \leq \sqrt{2}$

From here you can proceed with each one and finally put togheter the results (you have to intersect the solution of case 1 with the solution for case 2).

Hints:

**in the case 1** as $0\leq x \leq 1$ the quantities are all positive ant then you can square, the inequality becomes

$$\frac{25x^2}{16}\le {1+x} + 1-x -2\sqrt{1-x^2} \leq 2$$
$$\frac{25x^2}{16}\le 2 -2\sqrt{1-x^2} \leq 2$$
$$\frac{25x^2}{16}-2\le -2\sqrt{1-x^2} \leq 0$$
$$0 \le 2\sqrt{1-x^2} \leq 2-\frac{25x^2}{16}$$

**for case 2** it is better to set $y=-x$ in order to work with a positive unknown and proceed in a similar way to case 1

Comment: Thank you! But shouldn't it be $1 - x^{2} $ in the square root, where you take case 1 or am I missing something?

Comment: oh yes of course it’s a typo but it doesn’t change the reasoning :)

Answer (score 1):

Clearly, $-1\le x\le1$

$$(\sqrt{1+x}-\sqrt{1-x})^2=2-2\sqrt{1-x^2}\le2$$

$$\implies|\sqrt{1+x}-\sqrt{1-x}|\le\sqrt2$$

As $|\sqrt{1+x}-\sqrt{1-x}|\ge0,$

$|\sqrt{1+x}-\sqrt{1-x}|$ will be $\ge\dfrac{5x}4$ if $x<0$

Else for $x\ge0$

$$|\sqrt{1+x}-\sqrt{1-x}|\ge\dfrac{5x}4\iff16(\sqrt{1+x}-\sqrt{1-x})^2\ge(5x)^2$$

$$\iff16(2-2\sqrt{1-x^2})\ge25x^2\ \ \ \  (2)$$

Set $\sqrt{1-x^2}=y\implies0\le y\le1$ and $x^2=1-y^2$

$(2)\implies32-32y\ge25(1-y^2)\iff0\le25y^2-32y+7=(25y-7)(y-1)$

Either $(25y-7)(y-1)=0, y=?,?$

Else $(25y-7)(y-1)>0$

$\implies$ either $y>$max$\left(\dfrac7{25},1\right)=?$

or $y<$min$\left(\dfrac7{25},1\right)=?$